# Component Spacing Using GridLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout

I am having a problem using the Java `GridLayout`. To begin with, I am using the grid layout to simply put two `JLabel` components with their corresponding `JTextField` controls but the problem I find is that I have too much space between the label and the textField and I don't know how to correct it.

```
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel ();
    estableceBorde(panel2, "Info Jinete y Caballo   ");
    
    GridLayout panel21;
    panel21 = new GridLayout(2,2);
    panel21.setHgap(0);
    panel21.setVgap(10);
    panel2.setLayout(panel21);
    
    panel2.add(jinete);
    panel2.add(jinetet);
    panel2.add(caballo);
    panel2.add(caballot);
```

This is the capture with that spacing between the JLabel and JTextField that I mean:
[image: This is the capture with that spacing between the JLabel and JTextField that I mean]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with GridLayout is that all grid boxes must be exactly the same size, which is great if that is the layout that you desire, such as when you desire to create a chessboard, but this is not so great if you need a more flexible grid.  Myself, I would use a different layout, such as a GridBagLayout which gives greater flexibility to your positioning and gaps. For example:

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Foo001 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel (new GridBagLayout());
        
        GridBagConstraints gbc = createGbc(0, 0);
        
        panel2.add(new JLabel("Jinete"), createGbc(0, 0));
        panel2.add(new JTextField(15), createGbc(1, 0));
        panel2.add(new JLabel("Caballo"), createGbc(0, 1));
        panel2.add(new JTextField(15), createGbc(1, 1));
        
        panel2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Info Jinete y Caballo"));

        // Show the JPanel for demonstration purposes
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel2);
        
    }

    private static GridBagConstraints createGbc(int x, int y) {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = x;
        gbc.gridy = y;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        int gap = 3;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(gap, gap + 2 * gap * x, gap, gap);
        return gbc;
    }
}
```

The key to this code, and the difficulty in using GridBagLayout, is to correctly set the GridBagConstraints, something that I often do using a utility method, here `createGbc(...)`. The gridx and gridy settings are obvious, as this is where the components are placed relative to each other. The insets are the gaps around the components, and I've given the JTextFields a larger left inset to separate them a little more from the respective JLabels: `

```
new Insets(gap, gap + 2 * gap * x, gap, gap);
```

The left pad, `gap + 2 * gap * x` is `gap` size (here 3) when x is 0 (when at the first column), and is `gap` x 3 when x is 1.

Comment: I have tried it and everything has worked correctly for me. Apart from that, I have also understood it thanks to your code and your fantastic explanation. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @Juanan: you are welcome. Note though that my example of GridBagConstraints here is a bit simple, as there are several other properties that may need to be set in given situations, including weightx, weighty, .... There are good tutorials on the subject if you need to do more with use of this layout that you should look at.